# Приложение с библиотекой Websocket SignalR не устанавливается на Google Pixel

Tags: android, android-library

При подключении к проекту библиотеки [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client) приложение перестало устанавливатся на телефон Google Pixel.

При установке приложения вижу следущее сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько я понял нету скомпилиных либ под данную архитектуру процессора.

Вопрос: как можно это исправить? И есть ли какие то альтернативы?

**UPDATE:** возможно я использую старые версии библиотек, тогда вопрос в том где можно взять новые?

Comment: Вы кнопку OK нажать боитесь или это не решает проблему и окошко снова появляется?

Comment: Разумеется я нажимаю кнопку ок!

Comment: а после нажатия ок над оеще раз запустить и всё будет ок. это стандартная ошибка, когда у вас на телефоне уже есть apk, а вы код переписали

Comment: Да я понял, мне знакома эта циттуация когда на телефоне уже есть версия приложения и вы накатываете новую, но в таком случае ошибка другая, хоть и показывает похожее диалоговое окно, здесь проблема в другом!